# Is there an easier way to add properties to a class in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ide

I'm getting a bit more seasoned with my iPhone development but I still don't know everything. One thing that bugs the hell out of me is having to add properties to a class, because there are four steps involved:

1. Add a class member to the Header file
2. Add the property definition to the Header file
3. Add a synthesize declaration to the implementation file
4. Add a release statement to the dealloc method in the implementation file

Is there any easier way to do it? A hidden feature of XCode I don't know about? A tool of some  kind maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) might be what you're looking for. I've never used it personally but many Mac Developer podcasts give it rave reviews.